# Presidents of the French Tribunate from 1799 to 1807

Tags: france, french-revolution

who were the presidents of the French Tribunate from 1799 to 1807?
the French wiki only has an undated list of names (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribunat):

- Pierre Daunou
- Jean-Nicolas Démeunier
- Jean Bérenger
- Gabriel Malès
- François de Jaucourt
- Félix de Beaujour
- Pierre-François Duchesne

Comment: Perhaps the presidency was annually rotating? Then it might be the case that you have a chronological list on your hands actually.

Comment: IIRC the Tribunate presidency was supposed to run for two years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Léon Muel, the source for the full list of the members of the Tribunat in the Wikipedia article, provides a list of the presidents pp. 209-10.

[image]
[image]
**Page 209**: http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1413460/f217.image

**Page 210**: http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1413460/f218.image

**Full book:**

Muel, Léon. Précis historique des assemblées parlementaires et des hautes cours de justice en France de 1789 à 1895, d’après les documents officiels, par Léon Muel,... (Janvier 1896.). Guillaumin (Paris), 1896. http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1413460.

Comment: It is preferable to reproduce the contents of links in your answer, since websites/links can change or go dead.

Comment: The links are permalinks to the French National Library. I'm aware of the problem.I thought of extracting the information and publish in another format but the images were not uploading and for text format it would take too much time (if needed I can do it).

Comment: I find screenshots a convenient way to grab images from online books like these

Comment: I tried. I wanted to have the information directly in the answer (plus the links). I downloaded the PDF, made the screenshots of the two pages, put them in one image. Saved in PNG. Error uploading. Saved in JPG. Error uploading. And the links are permalinks. If the French National Library goes on, no problem... And I think I answered the question :)

Comment: I got the screengrabs for you--consider it a welcome-to-the-site gift!

Comment: Thanks! If needed I can provide the information in text format.